# how to change Gridview header text of columns using SQL values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I'm making a C# asp.net webpage that shows the data for certain items but I want to set the header's values in gridview so it will change the text depending on what item the user is viewing.

For example: the user wants to see data for Object A than it should go into the database find what values the table should show for the header for this item.

So if in the database it says: size, height, material than those three would be the headers text.

But if it's Object B than it should show the header text as following: size, length, color.

Each item would have different text for the header depending on what the user picks.

I already have the part done where it's getting the values from the database.  I'm having trouble on how to make the header dynamic using the header names from the database.

I saw this method that can be used in .cs page but it's not dynamic.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
   {
    e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "The new header";
   }
}
```

How can I get the values I'm reading from the sql commands and relate it to the header?  I just can't find the right syntax or method to relate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change the column definitions on a GridView.  For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    LoadTableDefs();
}

private void LoadTableDefs() {
    GridView1.Columns.Clear();
    if (/* condition 1 */) {
        TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
        tf.HeaderTemplate = "foo";
        tf.ItemTemplate = new ItemTemplate();
        tf.EditItemTemplate = new EditItemTemplate();
        GridView1.Columns.Add(tf);
    } else if (/* condition 2 */) {
        TemplateField tf2 = new TemplateField();
        ...
        GridView1.Columns.Add(tf2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tired this and the following lines are giving me errors:        tf.HeaderTemplate = "foo";                               tf.ItemTemplate = new ItemTemplate();
 tf.EditItemTemplate = new EditItemTemplate();                                  It doesn't like the right expression after the = sign.

Comment: Sorry, that line should be:

Comment: Sorry, the header template should be a class that implements [ITemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but this is trivial to implement.